# Efficient search through a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to search through a large data frame for a specific date. The date may have multiple values in the `data_value` column. After finding the date, I am extracting the maximum value from the set of possible values associated with that data.

Is there a way to make this more efficient? It runs slowly now.

```
max_temps = []
for date in dates:
    value = data_w[data_w['Date']==date]['Data_Value'].max()
    max_temps.append(value)
```

Comment: First apply isin in your large dataframe, then apply groupby and take max out of that.

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem properly then you need like this,

```
temp=data_w[data_w['Date'].isin(dates)]
print temp.groupby('Date')['Data_Value'].max()
```

Explanation:

First apply `isin` in your large dataframe, then apply `groupby` and take `max` out of that

Comment: yes, that helped a lot and is a lot more efficient. I basically need to create a new data frame with just the dates and max values. I have done that now in the following manner: `data_w_min = temp.groupby('Date')['Data_Value'].max()`.